# Visual Studio 2008 - Un/Comment button for css

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor

Is there a way to add a comment/uncomment css line/s button to the menu in the VS2008 css editor?  Other than adding a macro.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way, quite a few people have wondered why they'd leave this out.  [Here's the most detailed way I've seen to add a macro by Brian Schmitt.](http://www.brianschmitt.com/2009/09/how-to-comment-uncomment-code-selection.html)  I know it's not what you want, but he also outlines how to add it as a keybind, meaning you could make the Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C work for commenting lines in CSS files just like it does in code files now.  It's a little work to setup, but if you're used to the Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C it's really nice to have it work everywhere.

I believe it's the closest you can come to what you're after until they add it as a built in keybind.

Comment: I pretty much knew if I got an answer, it would have macros in it, but I put the condition in anyway.  Anyhoo, it works good so far, so I can't complain.  Thanks.